# Converting yes/no to integer type 1/0 (not just replacing) in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integer

After looking at several posts here, every post explains how to replace yes/no in a column with 1/0, but the datatype of those numbers remain 'object' and is not float or int (even after I use astype(int)), so I can't do further operation with them. My code is below.
Anyone knows how to convert datatype now from object to float or int?

```
df['Inter Plan'].replace({'no': 0, 'yes': 1}).astype(int)

print(df['Inter Plan'].dtypes)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) returns a pandas series, it is not done in place. Use:

```
df["Inter Plan"] = df['Inter Plan'].replace({'no': 0, 'yes': 1}).astype(int)
```

There is a `copy` option for `astype` which will allow you to do the operation in place, but because you are using `replace` as well, I don't think you'll be able to do it all in one line, so it is probably best to just use the above piece of code. In addition, the in-place option (which is setting `copy` to `False`) comes with a warning:

> be very careful setting `copy=False` as changes to values then may propagate to other pandas objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting to `str` before replacing:

```
df['Inter Plan'] = df['Inter Plan'].str.replace({'no': 0, 'yes': 1}).astype(int)
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this:

```
df['Inter Plan'].replace({'no': 0, 'yes': 1}, inplace=True).astype('int', copy=False)
```

Comment: I believe this will error with `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype'` because `inplace` on `replace` means it will return `None`, not a pandas Series.